# OpenCV adding face mask in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I'm trying to implement a face filter like snap chat. I have used opencv for recognizing the face but I'm unable to add the mask.

This is my code:

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;
{
    Mat grayscaleFrame;
    cvtColor(image, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(grayscaleFrame, grayscaleFrame);

    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grayscaleFrame, faces, 1.1, 10, HaarOptions, cv::Size(60, 60));
    for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Point pt3(faces[i].x + faces[i].width/2, faces[i].y + 20);
        cv::Size size(50,50);
        [self putMask:image placePoint:pt3 facesize:size];
    }
}
```

This code is for adding the mask:

```
- (void)putMask:(Mat&)image placePoint:(cv::Point)center facesize:(cv::Size)face_size
{
    Mat mask1,src1;
    resize(mask,mask1,face_size);
    cv::Rect roi(center.x - face_size.width/2, center.y - face_size.width/2, face_size.width, face_size.width);
    image(roi).copyTo(src1);

    Mat mask2,m,m1;
    threshold(mask2,mask2,230,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    std::vector<Mat> maskChannels(3),result_mask(3);
    split(mask1, maskChannels);
    bitwise_and(maskChannels[0],mask2,result_mask[0]);
    bitwise_and(maskChannels[1],mask2,result_mask[1]);
    bitwise_and(maskChannels[2],mask2,result_mask[2]);
    merge(result_mask,m );         //    imshow("m",m);

    mask2 = 255 - mask2;
    std::vector<Mat> srcChannels(3);
    split(src1, srcChannels);
    bitwise_and(srcChannels[0],mask2,result_mask[0]);
    bitwise_and(srcChannels[1],mask2,result_mask[1]);
    bitwise_and(srcChannels[2],mask2,result_mask[2]);
    merge(result_mask,m1 );        //    imshow("m1",m1);

    addWeighted(m,1,m1,1,0,m1);    //    imshow("m2",m1);

    m1.copyTo(image(roi));

}
```

Comment: You should show the mask and the initial image and the result, to get an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: actually im getting crash resize(mask,mask1,face_size); whether my above code is correct to set the mask

Comment: and where the variable mask comes from?  also later on, you create a mask2 variable and use it without loading anything into it in the next line as input and output.  Not sure what it is your workflow here. You find the face then resize a mask? shouldn't it be find face, create a black image with white ROI where the face was found and then apply this mask to the image? I think you have to re check and re do the putMask function

Comment: mask is global declaration. Can you suggest any sample project link to achieve this. thanks:)